# PHP - calculate current minute of a soccer match

Tags: php, date

I need some help to calculate the current minutes:seconds played in a soccer match, let's suppose a soccer match have :

```
$schedule='2014-02-13';
$start_time1='03:00 pm';
$end_time1='03:45 pm';
$start_time2='04:00 pm';
$end_time2='04:50 pm';
$start_extra_time1='05:10 pm';
$end_extra_time1='05:30 pm';
$start_extra_time2='05:35 pm';
$end_extra_time2='06:10 pm';
```

And I actually my current time is "05:32 pm", how I can calculate the current played minutes:seconds or (hours:minutes:second) of the match?

I have tried many solutions, like datediff, strtotime etc... but no luck, since there is some OFF time between these dates.

Thanks so much for helping.

Comment: Don't use strings to represent dates or times. Use [`datetime`](http://nl3.php.net/datetime) objects.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it using `DateTime()` and `DateInterval()`:

```
<?php
$schedule='2014-02-13';
$start_time1='03:00 pm';
$end_time1='03:45 pm';
$start_time2='04:00 pm';
$end_time2='04:50 pm';
$start_extra_time1='05:10 pm';
$end_extra_time1='05:30 pm';
$start_extra_time2='05:35 pm';
$end_extra_time2='06:10 pm';

$start1 = new DateTime($start_time1);
$end1   = new DateTime($end_time1);
$firstInterval = $start1->diff($end1);

$start2 = new DateTime($start_time2);
$end2   = new DateTime($end_time2);
$secondInterval = $start2->diff($end2);

$start3 = new DateTime($start_extra_time1);
$end3   = new DateTime($end_extra_time1);
$thirdInterval = $start3->diff($end3);

$start4 = new DateTime($start_extra_time2);
$end4   = new DateTime($end_extra_time2);
$fourthInterval = $start4->diff($end4);

$baseline = new DateTime();
$accrual  = clone $baseline;
$accrual->add($firstInterval);
$accrual->add($secondInterval);
$accrual->add($thirdInterval);
$accrual->add($fourthInterval);
$difference = $accrual->diff($baseline);
echo $difference->format('%h hours, %i minutes');
```

[**See it in action**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/JJ3pNG)

All this code does is:

1. create `DateTime()` objects representing the start and end time of each time interval.
2. get a `DateInterval()` object representing the difference between the two.
3. create a baseline (beginning point) `DateTime()` object
4. create a `DateTime()` object that we add our intervals to to represent time elapsed
5. echo out the difference between the two

You can shorten some of this if you use PHP 5.4 or newer:

```
$firstInterval = (new DateTime($start_time1))->diff((new DateTime($end_time1)));
$secondInterval = (new DateTime($start_time2))->diff((new DateTime($end_time2)));
$thirdInterval = (new DateTime($start_extra_time1))->diff((new DateTime($end_extra_time1)));
$fourthInterval = (new DateTime($start_extra_time2))->diff((new DateTime($end_extra_time2)));
```

and

```
$accrual->add($firstInterval)->add($secondInterval)->add($thirdInterval)->add($fourthInterval);
```

Comment: More than perfect John!!! Thank you.

I have few questions :

1- Possible to display seconds too?
2- Possible to set my time manually? for example if the soccer match is UTC, and I have UTC+5, there is solution for timezone difference?

Comment: To add seconds just use `%s seconds`. To add timezones to the mix you can use [`DateTimeZone()`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php). A quick Google search will show you how it is used.

Comment: Ok John, how I can add my date manually ? Instead of $baseline = new DateTime(); because this date can be passed via a parameter, after converting it to UTC.

Comment: Just pass it as a parameter to `DateTime()`

Comment: I got it. I have tested it, but something is wrong, my current soccer match dates : http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/644/1968154819.png

Now my time is 12:51 am, it display for me

{"response":"3 hours, 40 minutes, 20 seconds"}

If I refresh

{"response":"3 hours, 40 minutes, 13 seconds"}

Normally the game just started, I don't know why it show 3 hours passed.

Comment: One of the DateTime objects must be set incorrectly. If you look at the demo I set up you'll see it never changes.

Comment: here is my current date config, somehow it display one hour more : http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/644/1020371231.png

Comment: it display 2 hours and more passed in the game, but the game just started at 12am and I'm at 1am, so only around one hour. even the second half is not started, as I'm at 01:01am, the corret time must be : 37min, played in the match

Comment: The data in that image you just posted shows correct data. The response time was correct. I'm not sure where any problem is here.

Comment: I think it's wrong. check here : http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/644/1020371231.png

the game started at 12:04 am and the first half finished at 12:41 am.

I have set my time to 01:01 am here : (baseline : 2014-02-14 01:01 am)

so if I'm at 01:01am, the first half is finished then, so total minutes played are 37min (12:04->12:41).

the second half will start only at 01:14am

Comment: I think I see what is error, you counted the other parts of the match, and they are not started yet, I disabled them and it work now :

//$accrual->add($secondInterval);
//$accrual->add($thirdInterval);
//$accrual->add($fourthInterval);

How I can add this part only match are in them ?

Comment: Any help on it please John?

Answer (score 0):

I have added the solution of John, here is my code:

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set("Canada/Eastern");
$date="2014-02-14 14:00:00 +00";


$start_time1='09:00 am';
$end_time1='09:45 am';
$start_time2='10:00 am';
$end_time2='10:50 am';  
$start_extra_time1='';  
$end_extra_time1='';    
$start_extra_time2='';  
$end_extra_time2='';        

$start1 = new DateTime($start_time1);
$end1   = new DateTime($end_time1);
$firstInterval = $start1->diff($end1);

$start2 = new DateTime($start_time2);
$end2   = new DateTime($end_time2);
$secondInterval = $start2->diff($end2);

$start3 = new DateTime($start_extra_time1);
$end3   = new DateTime($end_extra_time1);
$thirdInterval = $start3->diff($end3);

$start4 = new DateTime($start_extra_time2);
$end4   = new DateTime($end_extra_time2);
$fourthInterval = $start4->diff($end4);

$baseline = new DateTime($date);
$baseline->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Canada/Eastern')); // -05

$accrual  = new DateTime();

$accrual->add($firstInterval);
$accrual->add($secondInterval);
$accrual->add($thirdInterval);
$accrual->add($fourthInterval);
$difference = $accrual->diff($baseline);

echo "baseline time :\n";
var_dump($baseline);
echo "accrual time :\n";
var_dump($accrual);

print json_encode(array('response'=>$difference->format('%h hours, %i minutes, %s seconds')));

?>
```

The game not started yet, but it show 1 hour passed in the game, how it's possible? http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/645/4891434894.png

Answer (score -1):

Mysql has a bug with **timediff**, so use this:

```
Time_To_Sec($currentime) - Time_To_Sec($end_time2) As time_seconds
```

Also check your time format,  avoid the use of strings as time or dates,  format as date/time entities.

Comment: What does this have to do with MySQL?

Comment: you`re right , didn`t  read  correctly. OP was asking about PHP,